# ServiceStack JSON Root Name

Tags: c#, json, servicestack

I've got a REST hello world service up and running with ServiceStack.

It currently returns JSON from a test object that looks like:

```
{"Name":"Value"}
```

The object is simply:

```
public class TestResponse { public string Name { get; set; } }
```

Does anyone how I can decorate the class to force a root name in the JSON so it appears like so:

```
 { root:{"Name":"Value"} }
```

Thanks.

Comment: `new { root = new TestResponse() { Name="Value" } }` or `new { root = new { Name="Value" } }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON returned matches the exact shape of the DTO you populate (i.e. the role of a DTO in the first place).
So you should change the DTO to represent the exact shape you want, e.g.

```
public class TestResponse {
    public TestRoot Root { get; set; }
}
public class TestRoot {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can return it as you would expect:

```
return new TestResponse { Root = new TestRoot { Name = "Value" } };
```

Or if you prefer, you could also use a Dictionary:

```
public class TestResponse {
    public TestResponse() {
       this.Root = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    }
    public Dictionary<string,string> Root { get; set; }
}
```

and return it with:

```
return new TestResponse { Root = { { "Name", "Value" } } };
```